# Rails partial locals not persisting when sent to another partial as its own local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, local-variables

I render a partial like so:

```
<%= render :partial => 'widgets/some_partial, :locals => {:foo => 'bar'} %>
```

So inside of `_some_partial.html.erb` I render two more partials like so:

```
<% #foo.nil? #=> false %>
<%= render :partial => 'widgets/another_partial', :locals => {:foo => foo} %>
`<%= render :partial => 'widgets/another_partial_again', :locals => {:foo => foo} %>`
```

The foo local variable renders fine in `some_partial.html.erb` and even in `another_partial_again.html.erb`. However, the foo variable is inaccessible in `another_partial.html.erb` even though I explicitly passed it in the render call.

What is happening here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by  "inaccessible"? Does it throw a `undefined local variable or method` or is it `nil`? Can you show the code that uses `foo` on these sub-partials?

Comment: it throws undefined local variable

Comment: the code was simple: <%= foo %>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. Turns out I was also rendering the same partial from the controller without sending the proper local variables. Thanks anyways!!!

Comment: I actually had the same problem, and my solution was exactly the same -- I figured it out when I saw your mistake :P

Comment: ugh me too! ha.

I changed my haml from: "- if myvar" to "- if defined?(myvar) && myvar"

Comment: same here, was passing the partial in AJAX, forgot to change the symbol

Answer (score 41):

I had the `undefined local variable or method` error come up for me too when I was rendering a partial with `:locals` defined.

However, I had a different issue causing my problem, so I thought I would share my solution in case it helps anyone else. (This page was the first result when I googled this error after all)

Basically just make sure you use `:partial => 'path/to/partial'` in your call to `render`.

I.e.

```
<%= render :partial => 'widgets/some_partial', :locals => {:foo => 'bar'} %>
```

NOT like I was doing:

```
<%= render 'widgets/some_partial', :locals => {:foo => 'bar'} %>
```

Easy for a rails/ruby newbie like me to miss.

Comment: +1 @asgeo1 Strange that you need `:partial` to make it work, but this does indeed work!

Comment: wow!!! Thanks ... I am just learning Ruby and I was totally confused regarding this error. I wish I could mod-up more points.

Comment: This solved my issue as well but I'm really curious why the `render partial: "partial_name", locals: { foo: "bar" }` method has to be used. I understand that we are *actually* rendering a partial. What I don't understand is how that differs from a view.

Comment: still useful in 2015!

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into this very old question cause I faced the same issue.
Turned out that with Rails 4+ if you are not using collections or layout the correct way is:

```
# Instead of <%= render partial: "account", locals: { account: @buyer } %>
<%= render "account", account: @buyer %>
```

As documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-Rendering+the+default+case).